# Get IPv4 Address from python, even with vpn on

Tags: python, ipv4

So I'm using socket to connect clients to the server. For that, I need the computer's ip. Currently, the best way I found is this:

```
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

I then use requests to tell my clients about my ip, and they connect. The issue here is that when my vpn is on, I get another host and that causes the clients to be unable to connect.
But when I open command prompt and type ipconfig, I get the correct ip regardless of the vpn status. So I need to get the same ip as would be shown under IPv4 in command prompt, is this possible in python?

I'm trying to get the server to work on any device regardless of exceptions such as this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way you retrieve the IP addresses of your system (most systems these days have multiple) uses the hostname of your system and therefore depends on i.e. DNS and your local hosts file. It will only give you one address, and can be quite unreliable, as you have seen with your VPN.

I'd recommend using the `netifaces` package. With it you can retrieve a list of all network interfaces and all their addresses.

An example from the manual:

```
>>> addrs = netifaces.ifaddresses('en0')
>>> addrs[netifaces.AF_INET]
[{'broadcast': '10.15.255.255', 'netmask': '255.240.0.0', 'addr': '10.0.1.4'}, {'broadcast': '192.168.0.255', 'addr': '192.168.0.47'}]
```

You should be able to install it with pip. The source repository is here: https://bitbucket.org/al45tair/netifaces

Comment: Can't seem to be able to do 'pip install netifaces'. My prompt looks like this, https://gyazo.com/6ae4e80bd7072f5505705d38bc8863a9 -- it does say error:  Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Do I need to get an item or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Netifaces is written in C, so you need a C compiler. I'm sorry, I haven't developed on Windows in over a decade, so I don't know how to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from subprocess import check_output
import re

IPV4_WIFI_PATTERN = re.compile(r'Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:((.|\n)*?)?\s+IPv4 Address.*:\s*(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})') 
IPV4_GENERAL_PATTERN = re.compile(r'IPv4 Address.*:\s*(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})') 
  
 def get_ipv4(): 
     try: 
         ipconfig_output = check_output(['ipconfig'], shell=True, text=True, encoding='iso8859-2') 
         wifi_match = IPV4_WIFI_PATTERN.findall(ipconfig_output) 
         if wifi_match: 
             return wifi_match[-1][-1] 
         return IPV4_GENERAL_PATTERN.findall(ipconfig_output)[-1] 
     except (IndexError, CalledProcessError, FileNotFoundError): 
         # fallback in case the ipv4 cannot be found in ipconfig 
         # return next((i[4][0] for i in socket.getaddrinfo(socket.gethostname(), None) if i[0] == socket.AF_INET)) 
         with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s: 
             try: 
                 # doesn't even have to be reachable 
                 s.connect(('192.168.1.2', 1)) 
                 ip = s.getsockname()[0] 
             except Exception: 
                 ip = '127.0.0.1' 
         return ip
```